# mysql: trying to group records by part of their values

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to do an sql select query to get certain records and group them by a certain field value.

I have a table named `courses` that looks like this:

```
+----+----------+
| id | shortname|
+----+----------+
3, 20115-2019a
4, 10112-2018a
5, 20115-2019b
6, 10112-2020a
7, 43112-2017a
```

the last part of the "shortname" field represts a semester. ("2019a", "2018a" etc.)
the number ("20115", "10112" etc.) is the course name.

I need an sql query that will get me the record with the latest semester of each course.

In the above example I want to the result to be:

- 5, 20115-2019b (because 2019b is the latest semester of 20115)
- 6, 10112-2020a (because 2020a is the latest semester of 10112)
- 7, 43112-2017a (because 2017a is the latest semester of 43112)

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT id, MAX(shortname)
FROM courses
```

It doesn't work, only give me the first record.

I managed to separate the course name from the semester, and tried to group by course name:

```
SELECT id, shortname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(shortname, "-", 1) AS coursename, 
SUBSTRING(shortname, POSITION("-" IN shortname)+1, 7) AS semester
FROM courses 
GROUP BY coursename
```

But that seems to give me the first instead of the latest course

Comment: I think result should be `5, 20115-2019b` instead of `3, 20115-2019b` right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

```
select B.id, B.shortname
        from courses B inner join

        (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(shortname, "-", 1) AS coursename
            , Max(SUBSTRING(shortname, POSITION("-" IN shortname)+1, 7)) AS semester
                FROM courses
                group by coursename ) A

        on B.shortname = CONCAT(A.coursename, "-",A.semester)
```

Here is fiddle for your question http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/907eb/10

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select c.* from courses c
where not exists (
  select 1 from courses
  where 
    left(shortname, locate('-', shortname) - 1) =
    left(c.shortname, locate('-', c.shortname) - 1)
    and 
    substr(shortname, locate('-', shortname) + 1) > 
    substr(c.shortname, locate('-', c.shortname) + 1)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hHdfkXJAjJJccMVmsS9jHo/0).
Results:

```
| id  | shortname   |
| --- | ----------- |
| 5   | 20115-2019b |
| 6   | 10112-2020a |
| 7   | 43112-2017a |
```

Comment: First time I read your answer, I can't understand your logic. But look closely, It is creative